# Erro ao conectar JDBC com o sql Server local

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Tento conectar o java com o Sql Server da minha maquina local mas recebo este erro

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost,
port 1434 has failed.
Error: Connection refused: connect. Please verify the connection properties and check that
a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port,
and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.
```

Minha Linha de conexão.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=ASSERTIVA_TESTE",
           "marcelo",
           "0869");`
```

Comment: Marcelo, tem certeza absoluta de que o SQL Server está na porta `1434`? O padrão é `1433`. O erro em questão não tem a ver com o Java ou o driver, mas com o servidor não ter sido encontrado.

Comment: Verdade é a porta 1433 mas continuo recebendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: O problema está então na instalação ou configuração do seu banco de dados. Você instalou mesmo o SQL Server na sua máquina local? O serviço está inicializado?

Comment: para funcionar com localhost o sql-server precisa ter o protocolo namePipe habilitado nas configurações, já deu uma checada lá?

Comment: Olha vi isso no Sql configuration manager e Pipes Nomeados esta ativo, TCP/IP também esta habilitado

Comment: Sem especificar o DB da para conectar? `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;`

Answer (score 0):

Use o JTDS. O Driver da Microsoft é amaldiçoado e fará você perder muito tempo tentando configurar até desistir e ficar frustrado para, só então, resolver usar o JTDS.

Comment: Você poderia elaborar o porque da sua resposta ? Para poder acrescentar;

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo,

Tente o seguinte: 
     Adicione nas regras do seu Firewall do Windows a porta 1433, para permitir a exceção.
     Dentro do Sql Manager Studio Habilite a opção "Allow remote Connections To This Server"
     No Configuration Manager Entre nas configurações com o Configuration Manager e Informe as propriedades do protocolo TCP/IP, em IP Addresses no menu IPAll informe a porta no campo TCP Port.
     Reinicie o serviço do SQL Server da sua instancia e tente novamente.

```
 Não sei se ajudara mais fiz desta forma e funcionou corretamente.

 O tutorial que ajudou muito foi: http://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/habilitando-o-acesso-remoto-no-sql-server-2008/
```